# Populate rows based on another row ( Copy Prices from branch 0, to all other branches)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to populate rows based on another row,

For example

- Update the Product Price table where branchID = 0
- to all other products where the branchid <> 0  based on each product code

In the table there is

7 rows of the same product, each row is meant to be identical, but the only difference is the branchid

I want all data from branch 0 row to populate the rest for the product

my current update script does run, but it uses up so much space on the transaction log that it fails, and it takes 2 hours to run

```
UPDATE  ProductPrice
    SET StandardSell = pp2.StandardSell,
        StandardBuy = pp2.StandardBuy,
        InternalCost = pp2.InternalCost,
        BuyPerID =  pp2.BuyPerID,
        AverageCostPerID = pp2.AverageCostPerID,
        InternalCostPerID = pp2.InternalCostPerID,
       SellPerID = pp2.SellPerID
FROM (SELECT BranchID, ProductID, StandardSell, StandardBuy,SellPerID, InternalCost,BuyPerID,AverageCostPerID,InternalCostPerID      
      FROM ProductPrice 
      WHERE BranchID = 0
     ) AS pp2 INNER JOIN
     ProductPrice AS pp1
     on pp1.ProductID = pp2.ProductID       
WHERE pp1.ProductID = pp2.ProductID
```

I want products to be updated with the prices from branch 0 to all other branches per product.

Comment: If you try to update in batches, it may not fill up transaction log.

Comment: Start with providing basic information. How many rows exist for BranchID = 0 and how many rows exists for all other Branches? And does this table have any triggers? Given your join logic, is it correct that the natural key for this table is <ProductID, BranchID>? And is this natural key (even if different) enforced with a constraint?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The first observation is that you should fix your data model.  Repeating the same columns on seven records is evidence that your data is not normalized.  The seven columns that you want to update should probably be in the `ProductPrice` table.

Then you want a `ProductBranch` table, with additional columns and the branch id.

That said, if you are stuck with the data model, you are stuck with an update that basically updates all rows.  Instead, create a new table with all the columns you want:

```
insert into temp_productprice
    select . . .
    from . . .;
```

Then truncate `productprice` and insert the new data into it.  A bulk insert is more efficient than a giant update.

Finally, you could also try using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select pp.*,
             max(case when branchid = 0 then StandardSell end) as StandardSell_0,
             max(case when branchid = 0 then StandardBuy end) as StandardBuy_0,
      from productprice pp
             . . .
     )
update toupdate
    set StandardSell = StandardSell_0,
        StandardBuy = StandardBuy_0,
        . . .
    from branchid <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions,

In the end I just gave the log file more space. Then let it run- it takes 2 hours though lol.

But its done

Thanks  the script i posted works for anyone elses use.